# Coverage works on Windows, but fails on Linux machines

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

I'm currently writing unit tests for Python, for this I'm using a combination of the built-in 'unittest' module and an external library called 'coverage'.

When generating a report on windows, I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\Me\Project> coverage report --include package/*
...
package\tests\scanner.py                 53      0   100%
package\tests\scans.py                  169     32    81%   202-235
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          1344    336    75%
```

However when I deploy this on a Linux based machine, this happens:

```
$ coverage report --include package/*
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------
No data to report.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

If I use the following, it does find the files but doesn't find any files in nested files:

```
$ coverage report -m package/**/*.py
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the script directory on Linux while deploying that command?

Comment: @HarshithThota yes, all other scripts I execute seem to work fine, it just seems to act really strangely when passing paths to coverage

Comment: Did you install python-dev and gcc support files before installing coverage?

Comment: @HarshithThota yup, the last command I showed does seem to work, but simply doesn't include all sub-files in my `package` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be an issue related to the wildcards in Bash. Doing the following worked:

```
coverage report -m unittest package/\*
```

Comment: Using hard-quotes is probably easier so you don't have to remember all the special bash characters: `coverage report -m unittest 'package/*'`